# Teapot riddle no.15 (fanmade)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Rules:
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

- **First Hint:**

  > My first teapot is sticky sweet
  >   My second's not all the time
- **Second Hint:**

  > My first teapot likes it hot,
  >   My second doesn't care about climate
- **Third Hint:**

  > My third teapot is hopefully sweet too,
  >   But you'll never know before you try

Good Luck and have fun!
And of course I'd like to thank @[Jannis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52327/jannis) for starting the teapot riddles!
<sub>Please forgive me if I break tradition by not linking to previous teapot riddles here. Their number is growing and you'll find them if you want. :)</sub>

Comment: no problem, but where is the final hint :P

Comment: @Jannis the riddle was easy enough to not need an easier final hint ^^

Comment: I know, i was joking around :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a

> DATE?

My first teapot is sticky sweet

> Date, the sticky sweet fruit.

My second's not all the time

> Only certain dates of the year are sticky or sweet as well. Could this refer to the fact that only certain dates were on [Madonna’s Sticky & Sweet tour](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_%26_Sweet_Tour)? One date occurs every 365 days or so, it doesn’t occur all the time?

My first teapot likes it hot,

> Dates grow in tropical conditions.

My second doesn't care about climate

> Dates on the calendar occur no matter the climate.

My third teapot is hopefully sweet too, 
 But you'll never know before you try

> This references going on a date - hopefully your date is sweet, but you won’t know before you go on it!

Comment: Yes it is! One hint is not yet correct though.

Comment: How does this look now, @Cashbee?

Comment: Nope. What I mean is the reason why I added the tag `wordplay`

Comment: Is the clue I modified the incorrect one, @Cashbee?

Comment: You modified two. Yes it's one of them :) muahaha

Comment: @Cashbee Whoops, I meant the top one. Forgot that people can’t read minds! ;p

Comment: hehehe, yes that's the clue I meant

Comment: Is my update the wordplay? @Cashbee

Comment: indeed it was. Well played! You see through my puzzles too well. But I guess that has nothing to do with the puzzles being mine :)

Comment: Too kind of you! Thanks very much, @Cashbee, great puzzle! :)

Comment: Also, I realized that 20 minutes before my post, someone posted the riddle "The perfect date". What a bad timing