# Teapot riddle no.16 (fan made)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

**Teapot Riddle no.16 (fan made).** 
*Proceed*.

> > **Rules:**
>
> *I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**.
>
> Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...).
>
> You try to figure out the word with my Hints.*

***Note***: I have decided to use American spelling as there are more people in America than Australia, and thus it is more likely that someone from America will view/answer this.

- **First Hint:**

  > My first teapot blows, and my second is rough. 
  >  One opens or closes, with one not enough.
- **Second Hint:**

  > My first teapot chills out, but hates a pillow. 
  >  My second gives thrills at the good copy's show.
- **Third Hint:**

  > My first teapot's fresh but its key is not new; 
  >  Felt cold on your flesh, perhaps, if it pushed through.
- **Final Hint (to make it easy):**

  > My second likes paper, its edge not as straight; 
  >  Whatever the flavor, it will soon update.

Good luck and have fun!
[Last teapot riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72462/teapot-riddle-no-15-fanmade). Big thanks to @[Jannis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52327/jannis) for making them!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83588/discussion-on-question-by-user477343-teapot-riddle-no-16-fan-made).

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain $\diamondsuit$ thanks for that. I will try not to have such discussions in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add onto @AHKieran

The answer is:

> Draft/ (Draught)

My first teapot blows, and my second is rough. 
One opens or closes, with one not enough.

> First teapot draft like a gust of wind, second like a draft in writing a paper or essay.

My first teapot chills out, but hates a pillow. 
My second gives thrills at the good copy's show.

> first teapot, a draft of wind is often cold or chilly. Second teapot good copy refers to final draft that is shown or performed.

My first teapot's fresh but its key is not new; 
Felt cold on your flesh, perhaps, if it pushed through.

> When a draft is string enough it can be felt through clothing and is cold on your skin.

My second likes paper, its edge not as straight; 
Whatever the flavor, it will soon update.

> Many first drafts are done on paper and updated and changed over time.

Comment: Yes, this is correct! You got it! Well done! When would you like the tick? :D

Comment: Sweet! I will take it whenever

Comment: Congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Answer (score 2):

Work in progress.

First teapot:

> blows, opens or closes, fresh, key is not new; cold on flesh; (if it pushed through)

Second teapot:

> rough, gives thrills at good copy's show; likes paper, edge not straight

Answer:

> Is it a sound like **Screech**? Like when you suddenly feel cold, or when you scribe on a piece of paper.

Comment: Sounds good ... would you screch before publishing a book?

Comment: I actually thought about a pen screeching on manuscript's paper. A weak one, I agree :)

Comment: what about a printer - it's no teapot but: some things are applying, then if its somwhat true, we have to figure who dislikes pillows

Comment: Yes, @Jannis is right. This does sound good, but is not the intended answer. Would you like to keep trying or have a hint? :P

Comment: @user477343 I like your riddle and would like to solve it without HInts

Comment: @Jannis okay. It will make sense once you get it, trust me :P

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the answer but i guess it's

> a Portal (door/dimensional portal)

First Hint

> A door can open/close
>  A Portal needs two sides/two stations

Second Hint

> Doors hate pillows/carpets and are hanging all around
>  I guess Playing Protal in reallife makes fun

Third Hint

> You can integrate a new door but still have the old key
>  Doors are probably cold, or the wind while open/closing doors

Final Hint

> I dont have damn clue

:D

Comment: No, it is not that... I *really* want to give out a hint that will most likely make you find the answer... but I don't want it to be too obvious! Remember the chat that we had? And I made those rhyming words? The answer rhymes with that :P

Comment: @user477343 you mean raft, shaft, craft  and daft ???

Comment: Yes... heheh ${}$

Comment: @user477343 I know it now: always choose **rock** nothing can go wrong with that

Comment: Hmm... considering you are German, I don't know if you have heard of this word before... :\

Comment: @user477343 i have a Translator for those things. even when its confusing me more than you do

Comment: Well, a portal is a good guess. Just keep trying, and you should get it. By "show" in "good copy's show" , I mean "revelation". Think what comes before the good copy (e.g. publishing a book).

Answer (score 1):

The word is:

> Draft(/Draught [British spelling for first teapot])

*My first teapot blows, and my second is rough. 
One opens or closes, with one not enough.*

> A draft blows through an open door, but also your first draft of an essay is often a rough draft. A draft can be strong enough to open/close windows/doors, a draft is not a final copy, it is not enough to get a good mark.

Comment: This is correct, but @gabbo1092 has a fuller answer. I will tick that answer and give you a $50$ rep bounty award (in an hour, that is; I can't do it until then.) :P